# UITableViewCell hidden content overlaps on other cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table,with settings that cell height is 40px.
If my cells have a label, image or any other component starting at 41px it will still appear in the table overlaping the cells underneath.
How to resolve this? I do not want the rest of the cell to be shown, just the height that is
set in my table settings.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using CustomCell or simple uitableviewcell?

Comment: It doesn't matter actually.

Comment: Why you are keeping elements beyond the bounds of the cell? Does it required?

Comment: can you put your code for heightForRowAtIndexPath and cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Am having the elements beyond the bouns because I want to show more information on click. So when user clicks the cell i change the height, and animate the components that are not to be visible when height is 40px

Comment: Then you can do one thing. You can hide elements when cell is unselected, once cells get selected you can unhide it

Comment: But then I am unable to create animation.

Comment: For UIView, hidden is an animatable property. Whatever animation you are applying, during that, unhide the hidden components of cell.

Answer (score 0):

Please add up these methods and try,

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.01;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return view;
}
```

Using this will be considered as end of data from data source. And rest cells will not be displayed.

[Will solve this issue - *If my cells have a label, image or any other component starting at 41px it will still appear in the table overlaping the cells underneath*]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the rest of the cells still gets displayed.

Comment: Have you set your delegates properly?

Comment: Yes, I checked, methods are being called but there are no changes.

Comment: I did, still overlaps. Any more ideas?

Comment: Have you set height for cells in heightForRowAtIndexPath method ?

Comment: Yes, I did but still the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the content of cell that is below the 40px level?  Add UIView to cell.contentView with white colour above the content of cell with 41px origin.y

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but just in case anyone else is running into this issue. If using IB, ensure "Clip Subviews" is checked on your table view cell. And this:

```
    self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

should do the same thing.

Comment: This works in iOS 7: `self.contentView.superview.clipsToBounds = YES;`
from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18878187/645697

Answer (score 0):

You didn't solve this problem because the point is not the UITableViewCell. It's Aspect Fill Mode of UIImageView.

Select the UIImageView in the SB, check this on!

[image]